# Способ сделать скриншот из Fragment в Android

Tags: android, android-fragment, view

Добрый день! Пролистал несколько тем насчет скриншотов, попробовал функции, у меня почему-то не работают. Приложение зависает при попытке сделать скриншот. Ситуация проста - При нажатии кнопки сделать скрин экрана, вызов идет во фрагменте. Если не сложно подскажите еще как можно обрезать скрин по размерам определенным, например надо только квадрат из центра скриншота. Спасибо!

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap b = view.getDrawingCache();
```

использовал эти функции, на них он виснет. В качестве View передавал корневой слой фрагмента он RelativeLayout

Answer (score 2):

Используйте данный метод :

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view, int totalHeight, int totalWidth) {
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(totalWidth,totalHeight , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable != null)
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        else
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        view.measure( View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(totalWidth,View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(totalHeight,View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        view.layout(0,0,totalWidth,totalHeight);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return returnedBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: Ошибка
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 360012 byte allocation with 227024 free bytes and 221KB until OOM

Comment: если передаю методу getView().getRootView()
то выскакивает ошибка, говорит что объект Bitmap = null при попытке результат метода установить в ImageView

Comment: пришлось перенести вызов метода в активность. там работает почему-то)